# Spring with Kotlin - final method in an open class is not able to access member variables

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a class say -

```
@Component
open class Foo @Autowired constructor(bar: Bar) {

    private val myList = listOf(1,2,3)

    open fun readFirst() {
        println(myList[0])
    }

    fun readAll() {
        myList.forEach { i -> println(i) }
    }
}
```

The method readFirst works fine and is able to access myList, but the method readAll throws a null pointer exception for myList.

If i make readAll open or i make the class and readFirst final by removing open keyword then also it works fine.

Is there a reason for this, or is this a bug.

NOTE: This is not the exact code that was failing, but this is an example of what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the Spring framework works its magic by creating hidden subclasses and overriding methods.

Kotlin, unlike Java, defaults to non-open (what Java calls `final`) for classes and methods, and needs the `open` keyword to make them open.  This is usually a Good Thing™, but breaks Spring, as you found.

One way to solve this is to mark all such classes and methods as `open`.

But it's easier to use the [compiler plug-in](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin).  That automatically makes all classes that use specific Spring annotations open.

Comment: According to what i have found, only ```@Configuration``` and ```@Bean``` needs to be open, since it is needed for spring to add some logic when we create the bean. Even if i remove open from the class, then too it works. It's just that with this combination it is failing for me